# Get parent id in django-mptt

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-mptt, mptt

I am using `django-mptt` and `jquery-treetable`.

I am printing my objects with:

```
<table>
{% for node in nodes %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ node }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

In `jquery-treetable` the `<tr>` element should have some attributes to identify which rows are children of which rows.

It needs to have the following setup

```
<table>
    <tr data-tt-id="1">
        <td>Parent</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-tt-id="2" data-tt-parent-id="1">
        <td>Child</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

but I can't seem to find the right template variables to identify the children correctly. I have only found `node.id`, `node.tree_id`, `node.level`, `node.lft`, and `node.rght`.

Answer (score 1):

If your nodes are MPTTModels then you should have a 'parent' relationship to 'self'. Assuming that is the case, you should be able to get the parent id by doing:

```
node.parent.id
```